# Loop Hibernate - Select (one-to-many / many-to-one) - JAXRS

Tags: java, sql, json, hibernate, jax-rs

I am new user of Hibernate and i have a problem. When i want get data of my database, Hibernate make a **infinite loop**.

My request :

```
Query q = s.createSQLQuery("SELECT resultat.*  FROM (SELECT r.* FROM application a JOIN configurationapplication ca ON a.id = ca.idApplication JOIN resultat r ON r.idApplication = a.id WHERE a.etat = 1 ORDER BY dateEnregistrement DESC) resultat group by resultat.idApplication").addEntity(ResultatBO.class);
```

The result :

```
Resultat ->
            Application 1 ->
                                List- Configuration 1 ->
                                                                   Application 1 ->
                                                                                         List- Configuration 1 ->
                                                                                                                            Application 1
```

I need to get the result associate at one application, the application associate at one List of Configuration and the configuration associate at one application. This is a loop ...

This is my configuration Hibernate.

**ApplicationBO**

```
<class lazy="false"
    name="ApplicationBO" table="application">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <property name="libelle" column="libelle" type="string" />
    <property name="etat" column="etat" type="boolean" />

    <bag name="lstConfApp" lazy="false" cascade="all">
        <key column="idApplication" />
        <one-to-many class="ConfigurationApplicationBO"/>
    </bag>
</class>
```

**ConfigurationApplicationBO**

```
<class lazy="true"
    name="ConfigurationApplicationBO"
    table="configurationapplication">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <property name="hostID" column="host_object_id" type="int" />
    <property name="serviceID" column="service_object_id" type="int" />
    <property name="etat" column="etat" type="boolean" />
    <property name="libelle" column="libelle" type="text" />

    <many-to-one name="Application" column="idApplication" cascade="all"/>
</class>
```

**ResultatBO**

```
<class  lazy="false" name="ResultatBO"
    table="resultat">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
    <property name="statut" column="statut" type="integer" />
    <property name="dateEnregistrement" column="dateEnregistrement" type="timestamp" />
    <property name="infoComplementaire" column="infoComplementaire" type="string" />

    <many-to-one name="application" column="idApplication"/>

</class>
```

I never use the relation ConfigurationApplication.getApplication(). I just have this propertie *application* when i save/update/delete the data.

I want too get a result where application.etat = 1 and there are at least count(configuration.etat=1) >0

Have you any idea to resolve this problem.
Thanks.

Sorry for my bad english :D .

**Edit 1 :**

The result of the request it's exposed at my API JAXRS. I have this error and for me the problem is hibernate. `org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->ResultatBO["application"]->ApplicationBO_$$_javassist_1[‌​"handler"])`

**Edit 2 :**

The code 
`@GET
@Produces("application/json") 
public Response get() { 
List<ResultatBO> lstRes = ContextServiceImpl.getInstance().getStatusApplications( HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession()); GenericEntity<List<ResultatBO>> entity;
entity = new GenericEntity<List<ResultatBO>>(lstRes) { }; 
return Response.ok(entity).build(); }`

**Edit 3 :**

Problem resolved. Thanx. I worked on the old version of my code i forgot to update my version :s .

The problem is on my hbm.xml file the mode lazy was at true, i modified the value at false and i add  the annotation **@JsonIgnore**.

Comment: f your data has a recursive reference then Hibernate will setup your "loop". It can easily do that since it will only fetch "Application 1" once and then fill it in wherever it is referenced. What is the actual problem? You're not really describing one here.

Comment: Yes so it was an X/Y problem. Sounds to me like you need to add some JSON serialization exclusions at proper points in your model. I don't know why you're dumping all that extra information in comments, you can just edit them into your question.